# Bazel build verbose compiler commands logging

Tags: c++, bazel

How can I increase the verbosity of the build process?
Bazel seems to print compiler commands only if something goes wrong during the build.

I would like to see which compiler comands the cc_library rule fires, even if everything seems to be fine, to debug linking problems.
I already tried various bazel command line parameters but nothing gives me the compiler commands :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the commands executed by Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983711/how-do-i-get-the-commands-executed-by-bazel)

Comment: Which is 2 months younger than this question. So why do you mark my question as a duplicate?

Comment: Because the other question presents the challenge in more detail, and has an answer with a citation.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```sh
bazel build --subcommands //my:target
```

The [`--subcommands`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/user-manual.html#flag--subcommands) option causes Bazel's execution phase to print the full command line for each command prior to executing it.

Comment: You also have to change something in the code base to make it rebuild--even if that just means deleting a parenthesis somewhere to make the build break.

Comment: Where is the official documentation for the `-s` option? Is there a long form of this short option which is more easy to Google?

Comment: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--subcommands
`bazel help build` prints:
`--[no]subcommands [-s] (true, pretty_print or false; default: "false")`

Comment: +1 to hnakamur's comment. I think people should usually use the verbose version of flags in stackoverflow answers because they are more explanatory. `bazel build --subcommands //my:target` is clear and easy to search for compared to `-s`.

Answer (score 17):

Useful information taken from Envoy's bazel readme (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/master/bazel/README.md)

When trying to understand what Bazel is doing, the -s and --explain options are useful. To have Bazel provide verbose output on which commands it is executing:

```
bazel build -s //source/...
```

To have Bazel emit to a text file the rationale for rebuilding a target:

```
bazel build --explain=file.txt //source/...
```

To get more verbose explanations:

```
bazel build --explain=file.txt --verbose_explanations //source/...
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also find the following useful in addition to the accepted answer of using `--subcommands` (`-s`):

```
bazel build --subcommands --verbose_failures //my:target
```

The [--verbose_failures](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#verbose-failures) option causes Bazel's execution phase to print the full command line for commands that failed.

Although it would seem the [--subcommands](https://bazel.build/docs/user-manual#subcommands) option supercedes it given it is documented to display *prior* to command execution, I have found cases (with bazel 5.2.0) where for a failing command, `--subcommands` alone shows only a portion of the command along with *<remaining N arguments skipped>*.  Using both `--subcommands` and `--verbose_failures` displays the full command line in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can generate the **compile_commands.json** file. I have created Shell scripts (under Linux) to automate that: https://github.com/vincent-picaud/Bazel_and_CompileCommands.