# How do I see the command line that `bazel run` executes?

Tags: bazel

[How do I get the commands executed by Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983711/how-do-i-get-the-commands-executed-by-bazel) answers a similar question for `bazel build`, and `--subcommands` works well for that. But `--subcommands` does not show the command that's executed for `bazel run`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just running the executable built by the target you give it, plus anything else that isn't a bazel flag. Determining what's a bazel flag follows common semantics: anything that doesn't start with `-` anywhere, and anything at all after `--`. Some examples:

`bazel run //foo:bar` runs `bar`.

`bazel run --subcommands //foo:bar` and `bazel run //foo:bar --subcommands` are both just running `bar`. There are no flags after `--` because there is no `--`.

`bazel run //foo:bar xyz` runs `bar xyz`, because `xyz` doesn't start with `-`. `bazel run //foo:bar -- xyz` also does the same thing

`bazel run //foo:bar -- --subcommands` runs `bar --subcommands`, without bazel interpreting `--subcommands`.

You can also use [--script_path](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--script_path) to output a shell script with the full command and environment setup written out.

Comment: `bar` is the name of a bazel target, not the name of an executable. For example, consider `nodejs_binary(name = "bar", ...)`. `bazel run :bar` presumably runs some nodejs binary with some arguments. I want to know which binary and what arguments. (Actually it turns out that it runs a shell script, but same idea.)

Comment: `--script_path` does get me what I'm looking for though! It would be great if `bazel run --subcommands` just output what `--script_path` writes to a file. Sometimes I just have to shake my head at bazel's UX...

Comment: `--subcommands` doesn't seem to even show the subcommands. They're truncated somehow. Cannot figure out how to see what command is actually executed.