# Bazel build prints no output or logs

Tags: build, bazel

I am new to Bazel and running my first build command `bazel build //path-to-code` however it logs/prints nothing on the terminal. I tried verbose, explain etc options but none of them worked.

Can someone help me debug this? Any pointer to exiting similar posts would also be helpful.

Comment: Nothing????????

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32823625/bazel-build-verbose-compiler-commands-logging